# How to block inserting rows in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet in which each row contains registration data for different vendors.

These entries are made by filling in cells in a single reserved row (row 3). Through the script, I created the MENU that calls the "Insert" function. That function creates a new row in the sheet (before row 5) and pastes the registration data filled in the reserved row (3).

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var vendors_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('vendors');

function onOpen() {
  ui.createMenu('MENU')
    .addItem('Insert', 'insert')
    .addToUi();
}

function insert() {
  vendors_sheet.insertRowBefore(5);
  vendors_sheet.getRange('A5:AF5').setValues(vendors_sheet.getRange('A3:AF3').getValues());
  vendors_sheet.getRange('A3:AF3').clearContent();
}
```

However, some spreadsheet users are manually inserting a new row in the sheet to enter the registration data.

[image: Do not allow this action.]

I would like a way to inhibit the insertion of new rows manually by the spreadsheet, but without blocking the editing of the cells. So that the only possible way is using the "Insert" option of the MENU. Does anyone know if this is possible? And how can I do this?

I hope I was clear in my explanation.

Comment: Not sure - you may be able to monitor the Change event for changeType = INSERT_ROW - and then do something to override the action?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your spreadsheet or knowing exactly what your script does. But you should be able to data protect some column in the sheet (even if it's a blank column that you add and then Hide), giving only yourself permission to edit that column. Then, if anyone else tries to insert a row, it would not allow them to, since it would interfere with the current layout of that protected column. You may need to edit your script to lift that column's protection, execute the rest, and then protect the column again at the end of the script run.

Comment: To my understanding it is not possible to block the button, however I think that this can be accomplished in a different way. As Erik Tyler mentioned, it would be good to have a minimal reproducible example with dummy data if you prefer so that we have a better idea and probably provide a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

#### Preventing users from inserting rows in a given sheet

These two triggered functions work together to prevent users from inserting rows into Sheet2.  The onSelectionChange() keeps feed range information into Properties Service and when onMyChange() occurs it deletes the row that was just added because it only runs on changeType == "INSERT_ROW"

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    let s = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range");
    let sh = e.source.getRange(s).getSheet();
    let row = e.source.getRange(s).getRow();
    if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2") {
      sh.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let rg = `${sh.getName()}!${e.range.getA1Notation()}`;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", rg);
  //e.source.toast(rg);
}
```

Admittedly, It's kind of a kluge

You will required installable onChange event (actually they're all installable) and onSelectionChange trigger.  This will not work for changes by other scripts, although it is interesting to note that other scripts can cause onSelectionChange to fire when they make selection changes with activate();

Comment: `let s = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range");`
Can you explain to me what "range" is representing in this part of the code?

Comment: It is just a property name that I made up to hold the value