# Automate: How to get a cell value each time a new row is added and replace the value in another sheet using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm organizing an event using Eventbrite, which I need to customise the check-in workflow. I'm able to create something using Zapier, but hit some limitations with the final step.

These are the steps I want to do on the event day:

1. When guest checks-in, lookup for Barcode # in my "Report" Sheet.
2. Add a new row to "Table Number" Sheet with "Barcode #" and "Table #".
3. Get "Table #" each time a new row is added.
4. Show "Table #" in "Display" Sheet, by replacing the current value.

Note: The table number is pre-populated before the event day. I'll download the attendee list when registration closes, and manually input the table number.

I managed to complete Step 1 & 2 using Zapier, and thought I can complete Step 3 & 4 using AppScript. However, I'm still quite new in this. Would appreciate some help.

[Link to my test Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GlXs7LVLen7v41DvC6nB7hUBKMZp4ytNBKWdL2KW0Y0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), especially the `onEdit()` trigger.

Comment: One of the problems with onChange is  that it does given you much information so in this answer I combined the used of onChange and onEdit together and it seems to me it might be useful to you at this time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71611078/7215091